# Can't seem to make a functional THREE.js collada loader

Tags: render, webgl, collada, three.js

I'm having issues getting a custom made collada object with no built in camera or lighting to render. I more or less copied what I had seen in a few collada examples to create my own loader, which looks like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var room, scene, stats;
loader.load('../Models/Rooms/boot.dae', function colladaReady( collada ){
    collada.scene.getChildByName('Cube',true).doubleSided = true;
    room = collada.scene;
    room.scale.x = room.scale.y = room.scale.z = 1;
    room.updateMatrix();
    init();
});
```

The init function is fairly basic and looks like this

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add( room );
scene.add( camera );
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

[Here](http://babbage.cs.missouri.edu/~cs4970sp11grp2/webgl_tests/Models/Rooms/boot.dae) is the actual object I'm trying to render. I have also tried it out with the monster.dae file that is in the examples folder without success. The Chrome javascript console isn't showing any errors, so I'm not quite sure where to look in my code. It all resembles functional examples, so I'm not sure why it's not functional. Is there something I'm unaware of that is relevant to collada loading?

Comment: Does anyone have any thought whatsoever on this?  I've been trying to get something to render for at least three days now with no luck, even with my code being identical to working examples and using the same files as those working examples.  I'm seriously at a loss here and this project I'm working on is really important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED: The item was rendering, but had no skin or texture associated with it.  So it was rendering at the same colour as the background, which understandably appears to not be rendering at all.  Discovered by adding a grid to the ground just to check.

Comment: Can you share your working code here with the grid? I think others may find it useful (myself included). Thanks!